# Issue with corba in Java

Tags: java, corba

I'm having an issue where I've written a Java App that works perfectly on my development machine and perfectly on a Lab system, however when I install it onto the client machine I get the following Error:

org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong? Am I missing a Jar file? or have the client maybe got the wrong version of Java Installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I've been a numpty and misinterpreted the exception.

The corba naming service that I am trying to connect to can't be found not the package...

Man do I feel stupid...